# Make HTML button same size as its background

Tags: html, css, button, background-image

Usually, you make a button with a given size:

```
<button style="width: 120px; height: 40px;">
Mememe
<button>
```

Then you add a background which is the same size as the button:

```
button
{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Obviously, if you want it to be 1:1, the image should be 120x40 px too.

But is there a way to make *the button* same size as the image is? (With neither IMG elements nor scripts).

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not by using only HTML and CSS. It is, however, possible by using either PHP (or some other server-side scripting language) or JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to get the size of the loaded image, using JavaScript, and then apply the appropriate style on your button:

```
var width = document.images[0].width;
var height = document.images[0].height;
var button = document.getElementById('button-id');
button.style.width = width;
button.style.height = height;
```